# Nothing getting stored in django non-rel for google app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I am unable to save anything in my django non-rel development project..
I have google app engine sdk installed with django non -rel.
I can access the django admin page but cannot login because neither superuser is getting saved anywhere.
I tried creating user in manage.py shell.
But after closing the shell window, the user object i saved earlier was not there.
Please help me how to save data to database in django-non-rel..

My settings.py file is -

```
# Django settings for bookncart project.

# Initialize App Engine and import the default settings (DB backend, etc.).
# If you want to use a different backend you have to remove all occurences
# of "djangoappengine" from this file.
from djangoappengine.settings_base import *

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

# Activate django-dbindexer for the default database
DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'dbindexer', 'TARGET': DATABASES['default']}

AUTOLOAD_SITECONF = 'indexes'

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = False

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'l@ng7t0n-q4eb_*#3r04f1r09jf=&emqddc4a0!=yrvz(tbr23'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # This loads the index definitions, so it has to come first
    'autoload.middleware.AutoloadMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    # 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'bookncart.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    # 'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djangotoolbox',
    'autoload',
    'dbindexer',

    # djangoappengine should come last, so it can override a few manage.py commands
    'djangoappengine',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

and urls.py file is -

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'bookncart.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^bookncart/', include('bookncart.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

the base settings for djangoappengine are these -

```
try:
    from dev_appserver_version import DEV_APPSERVER_VERSION
except ImportError:
    DEV_APPSERVER_VERSION = 2

# Initialize App Engine SDK if necessary.
try:
    from google.appengine.api import apiproxy_stub_map
except ImportError:
    from djangoappengine.boot import setup_env
    setup_env(DEV_APPSERVER_VERSION)

from djangoappengine.utils import on_production_server, have_appserver


DEBUG = not on_production_server
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djangoappengine.db',

        # Other settings which you might want to override in your
        # settings.py.

        # Activates high-replication support for remote_api.
        # 'HIGH_REPLICATION': True,

        # Switch to the App Engine for Business domain.
        # 'DOMAIN': 'googleplex.com',

        # Store db.Keys as values of ForeignKey or other related
        # fields. Warning: dump your data before, and reload it after
        # changing! Defaults to False if not set.
        # 'STORE_RELATIONS_AS_DB_KEYS': True,

        'DEV_APPSERVER_OPTIONS': {
            'use_sqlite': True,

            # Optional parameters for development environment.

            # Emulate the high-replication datastore locally.
            # TODO: Likely to break loaddata (some records missing).
            # 'high_replication' : True,

            # Setting to True will trigger exceptions if a needed index is missing
            # Setting to False will auto-generated index.yaml file
            # 'require_indexes': True,
        },
    },
}

if on_production_server:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'djangoappengine.mail.AsyncEmailBackend'
else:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'djangoappengine.mail.EmailBackend'

# Specify a queue name for the async. email backend.
EMAIL_QUEUE_NAME = 'default'

PREPARE_UPLOAD_BACKEND = 'djangoappengine.storage.prepare_upload'
SERVE_FILE_BACKEND = 'djangoappengine.storage.serve_file'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'djangoappengine.storage.BlobstoreStorage'
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 1024 * 1024
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = (
    'djangoappengine.storage.BlobstoreFileUploadHandler',
    'django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
)

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'TIMEOUT': 0,
    }
}

SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'

if not on_production_server:
    INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)
```

please help me how to get database settings working..
i am unable to find a solution from 2 days

Comment: Facing same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: no didnt found any solution..switched to using django with sql and discarded google app engine work.

Comment: Facing the same. @GeoJacob any update on this?

Comment: @sreekanth; I didn't got any exact solution for this, for the time being you can create one url say 

/create-superuser

and write the code for create superuser; 

User.objects.get_or_create(email='admin@domain.com', is_admin=True)

this user will be saved in datastore.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['<Name of Application in YAML>.appspot.com']
```

For more details on [ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)