# Django-nonrel with django app engine cannot access the admin interface

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

I have a Django app which I am trying to get to Django-nonrel so that I can get it on GAE. The problem though is that numerous times have I tried creating superuser for the admin interface still when I do **syncdb**, it shows me:

> You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have
>   any superusers defined.

everytime.Also, I am never able to login into my admin interface by the created superuser.
Also, when I do this:

```html
python manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.objects.all()
[]
```

SO no users are created it seems. I tried to look for the solution and and had a look at a few questions like these:

[django-nonrel and the admin page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498837/django-nonrel-and-the-admin-page)

and a few others. Didn't help either. 
I would like to mention that I am using zip downloaded version of django-nonrel 1.6 and djangoappengine by copying them in my project directory

Just for reference my **settings.py** and **app.yaml** files are as follows:

Settings.py:

```html
# Django settings for flogin project.

# Initialize App Engine and import the default settings (DB backend, etc.).
# If you want to use a different backend you have to remove all occurences
# of "djangoappengine" from this file.
from djangoappengine.settings_base import *
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'libs')



ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

# Activate django-dbindexer for the default database
DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'dbindexer', 'TARGET': DATABASES['default']}

AUTOLOAD_SITECONF = 'indexes'

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = False

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'some key not shown here'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # This loads the index definitions, so it has to come first
    'autoload.middleware.AutoloadMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'flogin.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    #'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2',
    'flogin',
    'djangoappengine',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'djangotoolbox',
    'autoload',
    'dbindexer',

    # djangoappengine should come last, so it can override a few manage.py commands
    
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

app.yaml

```html
application: flogin
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

builtins:
- remote_api: on

inbound_services:
- warmup

handlers:
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: djangoappengine.deferred.handler.application
  login: admin

- url: /_ah/stats/.*
  script: djangoappengine.appstats.application

- url: /media/admin
  static_dir: django/contrib/admin/media
  expiration: '0'

- url: /.*
  script: djangoappengine.main.application
```

Comment: I would also like to mention I also tried changing the the above DATABASES['default'] of the settings.py from what is given above to:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'dbindexer',
        'TARGET': 'gae',
    },
    'gae': {
        'ENGINE': 'djangoappengine.db',
    },
}

Didn't work either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32629024/1075066

Comment: Facing same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: Nopes, dude I did not.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had the same problem and I found a reason why it's happening. When you run manage.py with any command except 'runserver' djangoappengine creates in-memory database for that and I think it's a bug in djangoappengine here, so no changes is made to local database for 'syncdb' or 'shell' or 'createsuperuser', btw I use v1.7.1 of djangoappengine. When you run 'runserver' command, it first creates in-memory database, but then recreates it with proper local stored one.

So, how to fix it? The simpliest way is to patch djangoappengine/db/stubs.py,

In the method `def activate_stubs(self, connection):` replace

`self.activate_test_stubs(connection)`

with

`from .base import DATASTORE_PATHS
self.activate_test_stubs(connection, DATASTORE_PATHS['datastore_path'])`